# Symfony2,Doctrine,MongoDb: Unable to pass query result to view

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, odm

I'm trying to work my way through the DoctrineMongoDBBundle tutorial in the Symfony documentation book. I have created the test "Products" collection, and am able to insert into it without any problems, however, I can't seem to be able to read back out of it. Or at least, I can't get any result to print in my view.

The SymfonyProfiler is showing that the query is being executed. However, nothing shows up on my screen. And if I don't comment out my foreach loop in the view, then the toolbar doesn't even show up.

Controller Code:

```
/**
* @route("/dbReadTest2/{id}")
* @Template()
*/
public function showAction()
{
    $repository = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product');

    $products = $repository->findAll();

    return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'products' => $products,
    ));
}
```

View Code:

```
{% if products.count %}
  In if Block
  <ul>
  {% for product in products %}
    In For Loop
    <li>{{ product.name }} </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>. There are no products yet!</p>
{% endif %}
<p>End of Page</p>
```

The only output that I get after loading is "In If Block". None of the other comments show up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I work with doctrine this way:

Controller:

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeStoreBundle:Product")->findProducts();
```

ProductRepository:

```
class GalleryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
     public function findProducts(){
          return $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("TLWEntitiesBundle:Product")->findAll();
     }
}
```

The rest of the code seems ok.

Comment: your syntax is wrong at least in version 2.7 or 3.0 symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

@user2566987

1) definitely your codes in twig to access the passing $products variable is wrong. I don't have enough time to code it for you but i can guide you to the solution
2) replace all code in your view with `{{ dump(products) }}` then reload the page you will see all your data from there decide whether they are php data object or php data array and output them with the appropriate syntax. 
3) You can not access a property field of a class if they are not existing for example is `count` a private member of class products. I do not see it there in the link tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

i hope it helps.